# How to count all the distinct datepart (week) between 2 dates with different years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I need a way to count how many distinct weeks are between 2 dates with different years

I have managed to do something like this, the result here is fine,because I use a group by datepart(year) so if it exists the week nr 20 in 2018 and a week nr 20 in 2019 , I need to count both of them .

```
  with c as (
  select DISTINCT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,-1,[insertDate])) 'Weeks' 
  ,datepart(year,[insertDate])'x '
  from [Table]  
  where [insertDate] between '2018-01-01'and '2019-08-01'
  group by datepart(year,[insertDate]),DATEPART(WEEK, 
  DATEADD(DAY,-1,[insertDate]))
  ) 
  select count(c.weeks) from c
```

The query should work for every date interval, for example if I have the interval 2017-07-20 : 2019-08-26 , the logic should be something like :

```
count distinct datepart (week,x_insertDate) for year 2017 + 
count distinct datepart (week,x_insertDate) for year 2018 + 
count distinct datepart (week,x_insertDate) for year 2019
```

and return just the total as result.

Comment: Try DATEDIFF(WEEK, startDate,endDate).

Comment: Datediff returns all the weeks , I need only the datepart of my x_insertDate

Comment: Can you provide some example input data and expected output to help us understand better? I'm obviously not clear on what you're trying to achieve if you think Serg's suggestion of using `DATEDIFF` isn't a valid solution to you.